# LT1172 Spice model: switch current too high?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, switching-regulator

I am using LTSpice IV for Mac, which includes a model for the LT1172 switching regulator. Downloaded the demo circuit from LT's website ([this one](http://www.linear.com/docs/39912)). Ran it. Upon right click on the LT1172 symbol, I could also open another test circuit. Simulated this one as well.

Now: in the first circuit, at startup the switch current goes far above 2 A; should not it be limited to 1.25 A? And in the second circuit, the same behaviour at startup, and the current stays above 1.5 A even in steady state...

Am I missing something?

Comment: The abs max switch current limit for the LT1172 is between 2.5 and 3.5A, depending on temperature and duty cycle.  So depending on what they modeled and the application circuit you could see currents higher than 1.25A.

Comment: @JohnD Ah, so they modelled the average behaviour, not the minimum current limit... Since the device is declared as 1.25 A, I would expect this as a limit. But you are true, the Data Sheet reports as a maximum possible limit the three values 3, 3.5 and 2.5 A, each for a specified operating condition. Thank you.